# Why NoSuchElementException and how to fix it?

Tags: azure, scala, azure-databricks

I am working on the [Deployment of Purview ADB Lineage Solution Accelerator](https://github.com/microsoft/Purview-ADB-Lineage-Solution-Accelerator/blob/release/2.2/deploy-base.md) developed by `MS Azure` team. The tool's gitgub site is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Purview-ADB-Lineage-Solution-Accelerator).

I followed their instructions and deployed their tool on Azure. But when I run their sample `scala` file `abfss-in-abfss-out-olsample` The following code, gives the error shown below:

> NoSuchElementException: spark.openlineage.samplestorageaccount

**Code in Scala language**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType}

val storageServiceName = spark.conf.get("spark.openlineage.samplestorageaccount")
val storageContainerName = spark.conf.get("spark.openlineage.samplestoragecontainer")
val adlsRootPath = "wasbs://"+storageContainerName+"@"+storageServiceName+".blob.core.windows.net"
            
val storageKey = dbutils.secrets.get("purview-to-adb-kv", "storageAccessKey")
            
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key."+storageServiceName+".blob.core.windows.net", storageKey)
```

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error and how can we fix it

**UPDATE**: In the Spark Config in the `Advanced Options` section of the Databricks Cluster I have added the following content as suggested by item 4 of [Install OpenLineage on Your Databricks Cluster](https://github.com/microsoft/Purview-ADB-Lineage-Solution-Accelerator/blob/release/2.2/deploy-base.md#install-openlineage-on-your-databricks-cluster) section of the above mentioned tutorial.

**Spark config**

```
spark.openlineage.host https://functionapppv2dtbr8s6k.azurewebsites.net
spark.openlineage.url.param.code bmHFCiNI86nfgqwfkX86Lj5veclRds9Zb1NIJ48uRgNXAzFuQEueiQ==
spark.openlineage.namespace https://adb-1900514794152199.12#0160-060038-516wad48
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
spark.openlineage.version v1
```

Answer (score 1):

It means Spark Configuration (`spark.conf`) doesn't contain such a key.

You have to check how is the configuration setup/provided if you expect this key to be present.

Comment: I just added an **UPDATE** section to my post. In `Spark config` section of the `Advanced Options` section of the Cluster, I do not see key `samplestorageaccount`. Is there any other place in Databrics where this key needs to be added?